# uWSGI - chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 2629]

Tags: django, docker, uwsgi

I am unable to start a dockerized Django application using uWSGI.
Below is the configuration being used.

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.6
ENV PYTHONUNBUFFERED 1
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y swig libssl-dev dpkg-dev netcat unixodbc-dev python-dev libldap2-dev libsasl2-dev
RUN mkdir /code
WORKDIR /code
COPY app/ /code/
RUN pip install -U pip
ENV PIP_TRUSTED_HOST="pypi.python.org pypi.org files.pythonhosted.org"
RUN apt-get install ca-certificates
RUN pip install -Ur requirements.txt
RUN chmod -R 777 /code
CMD ["/code/run.sh"]
```

run.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

./manage.py migrate
uwsgi --ini uwsgi.ini
```

app/uwsgi.ini

```
[uwsgi]
http-socket = :8000
chdir = /opt/code/
module = app.wsgi:application
master = 1
processes = 2
threads = 2
```

Error when starting the container

```
Operations to perform:
  Apply all migrations: admin, api, auth, contenttypes, sessions
Running migrations:
  No migrations to apply.
[uWSGI] getting INI configuration from uwsgi.ini
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Wed May 30 05:35:23 2018] ***
compiled with version: 6.3.0 20170516 on 30 May 2018 05:34:47
os: Linux-4.9.12-moby #1 SMP Tue Feb 28 12:11:36 UTC 2017
nodename: 0a9f49a479c7
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 6
current working directory: /code
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) ***
chdir() to /opt/code/
chdir(): No such file or directory [core/uwsgi.c line 2629]
```

Can someone help me figure out what seems to be the problem with this configuration?

The following is the project structure -

```
project
|--app
   |--app
   |--requirements.txt
   |--run.sh
   |--uwsgi.ini
   |--manage.py
|--Dockerfile
```

Comment: Looks like you're copying everything into `/code` then `chdir`ing into `/opt/code`. What happens if you change your .ini file to `chdir` into `/code`?

Comment: Yes, that solved it. Thanks!

Comment: Notice: `ini` file doesn't support space. Remove space solved it.